# Decomposing Matrix Values into Two Numbers in a Specified Manner

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

Having this matrix I want to decompose the numerical values (those that are not None), in this case 6, 9, 9, 3, 5, and 4 into 2 numbers that added together give those numbers.

```py
matrix_aux = [
[None,    6, None,    9],
[   9, None,    3, None],
[None,    5,    4, None]
]
```

A combination should be left by placing an additional column in the matrix matrix_aux, and then an additional row, in which a decomposition of the numerical values that were in the original matrix_aux will be made.

A decomposition like this should follow, ensuring that all decompositions respect those already carried out previously. This would be a **correct output**:

```py
matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions = [
[None,    6, None,    9,    4],
[   9, None,    3, None,    2],
[None,    5,    4, None,    3],

[   7,    2,    1,    5      ]
]
```

Note that all decompositions respect each other mutually,

```
decomposed numerical value = row decomposition + column decomposition
6 = 4 + 2
9 = 4 + 5
9 = 2 + 7
3 = 2 + 1
5 = 3 + 2
4 = 3 + 1
```

To solve this problem, I think you should use a combination of techniques, including backtracking and dynamically updating the array.

```py
# Function to decompose a number into two numbers that sum up to that value
def decompose_number(number, previous_decompositions):
    for i in range(1, number):
        complement = number - i
        if i not in previous_decompositions.values() and complement not in previous_decompositions.values():
            return i, complement

# Find numeric values and their decompositions
decompositions = {}
for row in aux_matrix:
    for element in row:
        if element is not None:
            if element not in decompositions:
                decompositions[element] = decompose_number(element, decompositions)

# Add an additional column to the matrix
for row in aux_matrix:
    row.append(None)

# Add an additional row for decompositions
aux_matrix.append([None] * len(aux_matrix[0]))

# Add values and decompositions to the matrix
for i, row in enumerate(aux_matrix[:-1]):
    for j, element in enumerate(row[:-1]):
        if element is not None:
            row[-1] = decompositions[element][0]
            aux_matrix[-1][j] = decompositions[element][1]

for row in aux_matrix:
    print(row)
```

I have tried this code but it gives me decompositions that contradict each other, for example here it is saying that 3 = 3 + 1, which does not make sense

```py
[None,    6, None,    9,      1]
[   9, None,    3, None,      1]
[None,    5,    4, None,      1]

[   8,    4,    3,    8,   None]
```

Comment: @ScottHunter The question is how do I decompose the numerical values of the table (those that are not None), into 2 numerical values that together form it. They must be decomposed so that the numbers of the last row added to the numbers of the last column form all the numerical values of the matrix, an objective that I am not achieving with the code that I published in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be re-phrased as a linear system of equations and then solved with numpy.linalg.solve.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
from random import randint

matriz_aux = [
[None, 6, None, 9],
[9, None, 3, None],
[None, 5, 4, None],
]

matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions = copy(matriz_aux)

matriz_aux = np.array(matriz_aux)

rows, cols = matriz_aux.shape

seq = np.zeros((rows+cols, rows+cols))

vals = []

# Setup matrix representing system of equations
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if matriz_aux[i,j]:
            seq[len(vals), i] = 1
            seq[len(vals), rows + j] = 1
            vals.append(matriz_aux[i,j])

# Set arbitrary values so matrix is non-singular
for extra_eq in range(len(vals), rows+cols):
    seq[extra_eq, extra_eq] = 1
    vals.append(randint(0, 100))

dcmp = np.linalg.solve(seq, vals)

for row in range(rows):
    matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions[row].append(dcmp[row])

matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions.append(list(dcmp[rows:]))
```